# Knitting from rmd to html

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm trying to knit this rmd file for my class and I have to do it on the class server. Problem is I access to that server with a ssh connection (since I didn't want to install a virtual machine) and therefore can't use the RStudio really handy knit button

I've tried using **knitr()** and **rmarkdown::render()** and nothing seems to work.

So far i've tried :

```
require(knitr)
require(rmarkdown)
knit(file.rmd, file.md) 
makdownToHTML(file.md, file.html)
```

this allows me to knit the file, but won't add the theme, author name, date and toc that are necessary for this project

I've also tried :

```
rmarkdown::render(file.rmd)
```

Which gives me:

```
pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.
```

I've checked and for some reason the `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` is null on the server (even though it's supposed to be installed with RStudio that the rest of the class uses on the virtual machine)

Right now I am looking for **way to bypass the pandoc** or load the files in my home to be able to knit this rmd file once and for all...

Any idea on the matter??

Comment: can you ssh -X, then launch Rstudio on the server?

Comment: `knit` to markdown on remote and render to html locally?

Comment: I tried to but it is SOOO slow and it most of the time ends up with rstudio going *not responsive*
I haven't tried to render the file locally ... will do right away

Comment: rendering the .md file on my computer worked! Thanks!!!